# How to have a separated file in js that handles the API response in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to separate the api file from this page and wants to send states to the api and get response to main file

I want to structure my react project and set my APIs and methods that makes the calls in a separate file.

i have a class component that have API, I want to add a new file and call it submitFormAdd.js
function in this file i want to handle api call and response.

```
*** MAIN FILE ***



class APIForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        duration:'',
        price: '',
    }

// some function

*** want this code in different file ***

    submitFormAdd = async(e) => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/service', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                duration: this.state.duration,
                description: this.state.description,
                price: this.state.price,

            })
        }).then(response => response.json())
         
      /////// wants item response here 

            .then(item => {
                if (item) {
                    // do something
                }
                else {
                   // do somthing
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

    render() {
        return (
            //Some JSX
        );
    }
}

export default APIForm
```

Comment: In your other file, you should have a function that `return fetch(url, {options});`

Comment: refer react-hooks and custom hooks could be helpful to you. you can create simple functions that approve params and returns some value.
https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM simply look at these talks and you can have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in API file

```
    export const AddService = async (data) => {
      let d = {...data};
      try{
        let rs = await axios.put(URL,d)
        return rs.data.data
      }enter code here
      catch(e){
        return console.log("ERR");
      }
    }
```

and  in Main file

```
submitFormAdd = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (this.state.valid == true) {
            let rs = await AddService({
                name: this.state.name,
                duration: this.state.duration,
                description: this.state.description,
                price: this.state.price,
            });
            this.props.addItemToState(rs)
            this.props.toggle()
            NotificationManager.info("Service Added Successfully", 'Info', 2000);
        }
    }
```